# Using multipe recv() and send() calls in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Is it programtically accepted/correct/efficient to use multiple recv() and send() calls in c++ TCP socket programming, or should I use serialization and other methods to packetize my data/ split the data at delimeters?

For instance say I need to send multiple strings to be stored in multiple different variables, should I pack the data in one stream or send using multiple send/recv calls.

Comment: You can use as many sends as you like but it will al end up in one stream, and you will still have an unpacking problem at the other end. TCP is a byte-stream protocol, not a message protocol. This isn't a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a *stream* protocol. That means that the sender, the reciever or any element involved in the communication can split or re-assemble packets for any reason.

Because of that, the rules are:

- on the sender part, you can either send the bytes with many `send` calls or assemble them in a buffer before sending them. The main difference is that as `send` is a true system call it adds some overhead for a context change. That is the reason why the C and C++ libraries have provision for buffered IO
- on the receiver part, you cannot rely on the initial packet sizes to be unchanged but must read bytes in chunks and assemble them to re-build your structures if it matters.

Comment: So either option I provided is efficient?

Answer (score 2):

> For instance say I need to send multiple strings to be stored in multiple different variables, should I pack the data in one stream or send using multiple send/recv calls.

Another option is to use [gather-scatter I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O) with `sendmsg` where you can specify multiple buffers. I.e. you get the benefit of one syscall without having to copy multiple buffers into one.